# Approval button in mail from AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I followed [this tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/home/announcements/emailapprovalusinggooglescriptandaform). I want to make the same example. I understand that i now, "publish as service" is "deploy as web app". After i wrote the code and i submit the message, i get an email with 2 buttons(as links). Approve and reject. Here is my problem. No matter what option i choose i get the following message "Sorry, the file you have requested does not exist."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a code?

Have you tried the code below?

```
var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() + '?';
var approve = url + 'approval=true'+'&reply=' + response.email; 
var reject = url + 'approval=false'+'&reply=' + response.email;
```

There is a [new variant](https://gist.github.com/oshliaer/4ac96a14e628001fd530) of the James Ferreira's code.

Comment: I didn't try this new version. I will try it now. My url was defined a little bit different.
I tried this version and now it says that i don't have doGet(e) function, although i have it.

Comment: publish the new version